# using mysql variable in where clause with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm still struggling to find out the best possible solution for binding one date as variable in SQL with PDO. So far I programmed a function in PHP which approximates times in a specific date. I only have one date but the dirtiest solution which I found would be to bind it twice which I wouldn't risk to keep my code clean. So I was thinking to set a variable which will be used then in Where Clause. That's my code so far:

```
<?php
function approximateAppo($date){
    $link = OpenDB();
    try {
        $query = "SET @v1 = :date;
                  SELECT from, till
                  FROM termin
                  WHERE from >= CONVERT('@v1 08:00:00', DATETIME) 
                  AND till <= CONVERT('@v1 20:00:00', DATETIME) 
                  AND comp_id=:comp";
        $statement = $link->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':comp', $_SESSION['comp'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindValue(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $row = $statement->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        p($e);
    }
    CloseDB($link);
    return $row;
}
```

But it doesn't really work, what might be the issue in there? Or what is the best possible solution for solving the issue? I still haven't found anything similar for solving my case.

Comment: You run multiple query-statements inside one query. Separate them out and I think it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute multiple queries in a single call.

You can initialize a variable in a subquery.

Also, variables aren't replaced inside strings, you need to use `CONCAT()`.

```
$query = "SELECT from, till
          FROM termin
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @v1 := :date) AS x
          WHERE from >= CONVERT(CONCAT(@v1, ' 08:00:00'), DATETIME) 
          AND till <= CONVERT(CONCAT(@v1, ' 20:00:00'), DATETIME) 
          AND comp_id=:comp";
```

But there isn't really a need for the variable, you can use the `:date` placeholder twice.

```
$query = "SELECT from, till
          FROM termin
          WHERE from >= CONVERT(CONCAT(:date, ' 08:00:00'), DATETIME) 
          AND till <= CONVERT(CONCAT(:date, ' 20:00:00'), DATETIME) 
          AND comp_id=:comp";
```

Comment: yes, CONCAT was the key. Because when I tried to use :date placeholder twice I got an error

Comment: Placeholders also can't be used inside strings. You probably got an error because it didn't find the placeholder.